# Dropdown Required field validator

Tags: c#

I have one drop down and it fills the value automatically from database. For that I'm using the following code in the front-end:

```
public void des_fill()
{
     string q = "SELECT -1 AS pick_det_id,'' AS pick_det_name UNION select pick_det_id,pick_det_name from tbl_pick_list_detail where pick_hdr_id=(select pick_hdr_id from tbl_pick_list_header where pick_hdr_name='Designation')";
     isopen();
     conn.Open();
     code cd = new code();
     SqlDataReader dr = cd.Reader(q);
     ddlDes.DataSource = dr;
     ddlDes.DataValueField = "pick_det_id";
     ddlDes.DataTextField = "pick_det_name";
     ddlDes.DataBind();
     conn.Close();
}
```

I am using this:

```
SELECT -1 AS pick_det_id,'' AS pick_det_name UNION
```

for the starting dropdown value as empty.

But by using this required field is not working. When I click the Save button it doesn't asks for required field, and saves the record.

Comment: Is this web or Windows app?, and the other question, are you using RequiredFieldValidator you mean if web?

Comment: yes.It is a web application

Comment: Please look to my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@thiru for required field validator place InitialValue=0
`<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFVQualification" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlQualification" CssClass="requiredfieldvalidatorstyle" Display="Static" ErrorMessage="*" InitialValue="0"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>`

here InitalValue refers to the the starting Index of the DropDown

Comment: I fill the Dropdown values from database.At the time of running,I need dropdown with empty value.Thats why I am adding a one query with UNION.

Comment: yeah correct.Instead of -Select- I am using empty string(" ").thats it. See my code for review

Answer (score 0):

do the following, add text box with ValidationGroup and validate that group on c# level as the following:

for Textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="FirstName" runat="server" 
        AutoPostBack="false" ValidationGroup="UserInfor"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
     runat="server" ControlToValidate="FirstName"    
     ErrorMessage="First Name is requried" ForeColor="Red"
     ValidationGroup="UserInfor">    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

for dropdownlist, you should add value InitialValue as the following:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddAge"  ValidationGroup="UserInfor">
<asp:ListItem Value="-1" text="Select a Value">
<asp:ListItem Value="15" text="15 years">
<asp:ListItem Value="20" text="20 years">
<asp:ListItem Value="30" text="30 years">
</asp:DropDownList>


<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2"
     runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddAge"   InitialValue="-1"  
     ErrorMessage="Age requried" ForeColor="Red"
     ValidationGroup="UserInfor">    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

then in the c# level, add the following:

```
Validate("UserInfor");
    if (Page.IsValid) {
                lblOutput.Text = "Required field is filled!";
             }
             else {
                lblOutput.Text = "Required field is empty!";
             }
```

Comment: I want validation for dropdown

Comment: Here you add the dropdown values directly.But I fill the dropdown values from database.By getting the value from database it only takes the values from 0,1,2...

Comment: Simply then, after you bind the data from the c#, you have to add  ddAge.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select One", "-1"));